# HP DV7 Ethernet Intermittent flashes

Tags: networking, 10.10, hp-pavilion

I Have an HP dv7 laptop with Ubuntu 10.10 installed
when i plug the cable no connection is established and a white light starts to flashes intermittent, the system tells me that no connection is active
I tried to reinstall the OS but nothing works.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found the problem was about the "weak-on"  setting of the eth configuration.
To find it I installed the ethtool to discover all the ethernet configuration settings, as this post suggests [Resolution Post](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-854487.html)

..and incredibly what was the solution?...
..first shut down the laptop
..second REMOVE the battery... oh my...
..third ... everything works!! incredible...

hope this helps